# CASE WHEN rownum() return rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a family_expenses table that looked like below:

```
family_id    bank_code    amount    year   month
  001          LB         130.00    2017     1
  001          MB         200.00    2017     1
  001          CB          78.00    2017     2
  001          SB          69.00    2017     3
  009          LB          78.00    2017     1
```

The table above have some other several columns.

What I need to do is get all the records for a family id and combine it with my another sub-query from another table. I did some query using CASE WHEN. 
My query is as below:

```
 SELECT
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 1 THEN t.bank_code ELSE '' END
) as bank_code1,
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 1 THEN t.amount ELSE 0.00 END
) as amt1,
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 2 THEN t.bank_code ELSE '' END
) as bank_code2,
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 2 THEN t.amount ELSE 0.00 END
) as amt2,
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 3 THEN t.bank_code ELSE '' END
) as bank_code3,
(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 3 THEN t.amount ELSE 0.00 END
) as amt3
FROM
(
select  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by family_id Order by family_id, bank_code) 
as rownum, 
family_id, bank_code, AMOUNT
from family_expenses
where year = 2017 and month = 1
and family_id= 001
) t
```

The result display 2 rows of records.

```
bank_code1     amt1       bank_code2   amt2    bank_code3     amt3
   LB         130.00
                             MB       200.00
```

How can I make the output display all columns show result in a single row?

Expected output:

```
bank_code1     amt1       bank_code2   amt2    bank_code3     amt3
   LB         130.00         MB       200.00
```

Comment: Use `MAX(CASE...)`? Also IMO you should leave out the `ELSE` part of those case statements (making the results `NULL` instead of a blank space/0.00), though that's up to you, I guess.

Comment: I tried to use MAX(CASE...) and leave out the ELSE like you suggested but it still return 2 rows.

Comment: Um, I'm guessing that's not the whole query then? The only reason you'd get multiple rows like that is if you're grouping by something that causes there to be multiple rows. e.g. You're not grouping by bank code, are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (just a wee modification of your original code)...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#family_expenses', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #family_expenses;

CREATE TABLE #family_expenses (
    family_id CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    bank_code CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    amount MONEY NOT NULL,
    [year] INT NOT NULL,
    [month] TINYINT NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #family_expenses (family_id, bank_code, amount, [year], [month]) VALUES
    ('001', 'LB', 130.00, 2017, 1),
    ('001', 'MB', 200.00, 2017, 1),
    ('001', 'CB', 78.00, 2017, 2),
    ('001', 'SB', 69.00, 2017, 3),
    ('009', 'LB', 78.00, 2017, 1);

SELECT
    t.family_id,
    bank_code1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 1 THEN t.bank_code END ),
    amt1 = SUM(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 1 THEN t.amount END),
    bank_code2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 2 THEN t.bank_code END ),
    amt2 = SUM(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 2 THEN t.amount END ),
    bank_code3 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 3 THEN t.bank_code END ),
    amt3 = SUM(CASE WHEN t.rownum = 3 THEN t.amount ELSE 0.00 END )
FROM
    (   
    SELECT
        rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fe.family_id ORDER BY fe.family_id, fe.bank_code ),
        fe.family_id,
        fe.bank_code,
        fe.amount
    FROM
        #family_expenses fe
    WHERE
        fe.year = 2017
        AND fe.month = 1
        AND fe.family_id = '001'
    ) t
GROUP BY
    t.family_id;
```

results...

```
family_id bank_code1 amt1                  bank_code2 amt2                  bank_code3 amt3
--------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- --------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------
001       LB         130.00                MB         200.00                NULL       0.0000
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I get a single row just like I want to. Thank you so much and have a great day ahead :)

Comment: You're welcome. This is the same idea that was being expressed by others, in earlier comments... Sometimes it's just easier to grasp the idea after you actually see a working example. Any way, I really appreciate the feedback and you have a great day as well. :)